# Powershell loop if VPN-connection is already existing?

Tags: powershell, loops, vpn

I made a powershell script for my Company to add a VPN connection on an Laptop.

Add-VpnConnection -Name "****" -ServerAddress "*****" -EncryptionLevel "Required" -AuthenticationMethod "MSChapv2"
Add-VpnConnectionRoute -ConnectionName "******" -DestinationPrefix ****** -RouteMetric 5
Set-VpnConnection "*******" -DnsSuffix ******

I integrated the powershell-script into the Windows startup Folder. But the Script is showing somth if the VPN connection has been already created "VPN connection is allready existing and cant be created". Now i want to build a loop where the powershell script checks if the VPN connections has allready been created and if not the powershell script should create the VPN connection. Somebody knows how to? thank u all

Answer (score 0):

Use `Get-VpnConnection` to gather all existing VPN Connections.

Now iterate through all connection names or destination/server addresses (or what ever connection identifier fits in your scenarion the most)

```
$allvpns = Get-VpnConnection
$yoursearchedvpnname = "TestVPN1"

foreach ($vpn in $allvpns) {
  if ($vpn.name -eq $yoursearchedvpnname) {
  Write-Host "VPN already exists"
  } else {
    Add-VpnConnection -Name "" -ServerAddress "" -EncryptionLevel "Required" - AuthenticationMethod "MSChapv2" 

    Add-VpnConnectionRoute -ConnectionName "" -DestinationPrefix ****** -RouteMetric 5 Set-VpnConnection "****" -DnsSuffix ******

  }

}
```

For more information about `Get-VpnConnection` take a look here: [MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/vpnclient/get-vpnconnection?view=windowsserver2022-ps)